# Flat Procedural transition

Tags: shaders, faces, displacement, procedural

Is there any way to create flat transition using shaders(nodes) just like in second picture? Is it even possible with shaders? I tried constant ColorRamp but it goes half way through, not full face or triangle[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Whats your goal? Are there only those flat plateaus and wich should have one color from bottom up? In that case a constant Color Ramp + Mapping node should do the trick

Comment: Another way would be to apply your material by hand after box-selecting from side view+orthogonal

Comment: I want to create low poly terrain with tris fully colored, so that tris is only ground or only water

Comment: are you using subdivision surface modifier?

Comment: Applying materials by hand isn't possible since terrain is quite large and generated on the fly

Comment: is the material curved or is it flat with diffrent sized heights? because if its flat it would be easy to do it "by hand"

Comment: after a seconed look id say that the porblem comes from distorted tris + subdiv mod, yes?

Comment: can you tell me what you did to active the shader-displacement, trying but cant replicate it in my new files.. acts just like normal map without height-displacement.

Comment: Found it: Material Tab>Settings>Surface>Displacement> From Bump only to Displacement only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Answer: You can use a Mapping Node with a constant ColorRamp to do some shading via global height or via other texture coordinate inputs

[image]

[image]

(I think that the problem comes from bent polygons, because you moved single vertices from the subdivided plane. Therefore maybe a triangulate modifier could also help.)
turned out it wasnt that, but the height-displacement is done via shader-displacent from a noise map witch also was wrongfully pluged in as color
[image]

Specific Answer for uploaded file:
there you used a standard noise map for colorisation, I replaced it with the setup from this answer:

[image]

because of the huge scale of your mesh you have to scale up the object coordinate input in the mapping node, then it works

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution, but as I said and as in your example, tris between green and red aren't fully colored, like they would be with different materials. If in shaders it not possible, Python script would be nice

Comment: strange, could you upload a file? the mapping-node setup should color everything by height without exeption.. maby there is realy a seconed material?

Comment: Added file in post

Comment: That is is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. But when I do it, it makes weird result [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LopHlbc1PTrhxi40RmejZtIdI61tB241)

Comment: Maybe there was something with the axis beeing inverted in your file you uploaded, therefore no rotation was necessary, When you do it in a new file you should do it like in the first node setup (img2) of my answer and rotate the coordinated in the mapping node y:90

Comment: Could you send file? Also is there any way to use tris rather than pixel shaders?

Comment: You maybe mean vertex color with "tris shader"?

Comment: Heres the fix of your file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52215

Comment: For new files just use the node setup from from pic 2